# Catalog URL Rewrites - Index Management and rebuild required indexes in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, admin-panel, reindex, indexing

[image]

I am seeing this message in the Magento admin-area:

> One or more of the Indexes are not up to date: Catalog URL Rewrites.
>   Click here to go to **Index Management** and rebuild required indexes.

I already Read this article: [Product Attributes - Index Management and rebuild required indexes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115407/product-attributes-index-management-and-rebuild-required-indexes)

But I have not found a solution.

Comment: What is your Magento version? version 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use crons to run indexers frequently. You can run indexers once per day or whenever needed. Product usally gets updated on each save with Observers/Events. Same goes for Catalog Category Details

You can run indexing manually:

```
$ php shell/indexer.php -- --reindexall
```

or put it to cron:

```
$ crontab -e
* 4 * * * php shell/indexer.php -- --reindexall
```

Comment: I already try this but same shown in shell.